# How to add a prefix to each line with m4

Tags: regex, m4

I process a program file (in fact assembler) with m4.
I can suppress lines using

```
changequote({,})dnl
define({_SUPPRESSED}, )dnl
_SUPPRESSED({
jan
piet
})
```

Now I want to changes the lines to assembler comment instead of just
suppressing them:

```
; jan
; piet
```

Is that possible with m4 e.g. using patsubst? 
How can it be done?

Note:
Despite much experimenting I didn't manage. E.g. the following fails.

```
define({pie}, {patsubst($1,{\n},{\n;})})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define(`pie',`patsubst(`$1',`^.*$',`; &')')
pie(`jan
piet')
```

Note the string delimiters around `patsubst` (in `pie`'s definition)! Without it the `m4` expands the `patsubst` at reading (not at using) `pie`'s definition. With delimitiers it will be a string and expand only when call `pie` macro.

Of course you can use `{` and `}` as string delimitiers.

Comment: It worked but it replaces all lines with "; &".  If in my original I replace "\n" with "^" it turns all lines into comment as intended. The quotes around $1 are also important, otherwise comment lines cannot contain comma's ",".

Comment: Yes, the replace of "^" is simplier :)